# MySQL crosstab counts number of IDs belonging to categories

Tags: mysql, crosstab

In mySQL I have a table `ID_Cat` below showing every ID belonging to which categories. Some ID's can belong to more than one categories.

[image]

I would like to do a `crosstab` count and fill in the count of IDs as below like a matrix.

[image]

Currently I have one select to count and then an update statement for each cell as below. Is there a better way doing this?

```
select count(*) into Int_Count
from 
( 
select ID_Member,count(distinct Cat_Name)
from ID_Cat
where Cat_Name='Cat1'
group by ID_Member
having count(distinct Cat)=1
) t;

update crosstab
set Cat1=In_count
where Cat_name='Cat1';
```

Comment: A common question, try searching mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation

Comment: A bit harder than that. The row titles and col titles are the same here